# Spring SpEL logical operators

Tags: spring, spring-el

In Spring expression language (SpEL) each textual relational operator has a symbolic equivalent. For example, `eq` can be written as `==`, and `lt` can be written as `<` (source [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#d0e11934)).

The logical operators, however, don't have a symbolic equivalent - at least as far as I can tell. I have to use `and` and `or`, the expected notation of `&` and `|` is just not there (for some reason `not` is different, it has the `!` equivalent).

Any idea if `&` and `|` are available, or if it is possible to extend Spring to support them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take a look at `org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.Tokenizer` in method `process()` where you will realize |, &, || and && are not supported. Adding this would require to subclass the Tokenizer and also to subclass the `org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser` because in its .doParseExpression()` method the Tokenizer is instantiated directly... Source of Spring 3.1 version was taken by me.

Comment: Support for && was added in 3.2.2